# Interpreter can find a 3rd party module but WIN-R and command line can't

Tags: python, module

I have installed a 3rd party module named `pyperclip` to my `\python31\Lib\site-packages` folder using `pip install --target` as I also have python 2.7 on the computer and it appears modules are put in 2.7 as a default.

I can run the script below through IDLE just fine.

```
import pyperclip
import shelve
import sys
import os

curdir = os.getcwd()
mc_shelf = shelve.open(os.path.join(curdir, "mcb2"))

# save clipboard content
if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == "save":
    mc_shelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
    print("Saved contents of clipboard to keyword \"{}\".".format(sys.argv[2]))
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    keyword = sys.argv[1].lower()
    if keyword == "list":
        pyperclip.copy(", ".join(keyword for keyword in mc_shelf))
        print("Copied list to clipboard.")
    elif keyword in mc_shelf:
        pyperclip.copy(mc_shelf[keyword])
        print("Pasted text to clipboard.")
mc_shelf.close()
```

However using WIN-R/ the command line I get an ImportError, eg:

```
PS C:\users\dave\Desktop\2016Coding\AutomateBoring\8-RWFiles> py.exe mcb2.pyw save dave
py.exe : Traceback (most recent call last):
At line:1 char:1
+ py.exe mcb2.pyw save dave
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Traceback (most recent call last)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

  File "mcb2.pyw", line 7, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ImportError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

What exactly might be going on here? Is it something to do with the paths used by each application? I've set environment variables, and set a pythonpath in system variables(this in particular led to a different error) but to be quite honest I'm plain confused.

Attempt at using pip3 to install:

```
PS C:\> pip install pyperclip
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyperclip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages

PS C:\> pip3 install pyperclip
pip3 : The term 'pip3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip3 install pyperclip
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Another day, more problems. It seems the term 'pip' is now not recognized at all on my computer. I have no idea why. I have briefly read some info which highlights my version of python (3.1) has a pip bug. Is there any merit in wiping both python 2.7 and 3.1, installing 3.4 and going from there? At this point I'd like to spend time learning to code, as it seems an easy 1/3 of my available study time is taken up issues such as these.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install packages using `pip3` if you want it to install in your Python3 environment. IE

```
pip3 install pyperclip
```

> I have installed a 3rd party module named pyperclip to my \python31\Lib\site-packages folder using `pip install --target`

What you're effectively doing here is using the Python2 version of pip to try to install a Python3 package. Your Python3 environment has its own version of `pip` -- If your Python3 environment is also in your PATH, you can call pip for Python3 by `pip3`

Comment: Thanks. Python 3 is in my Path, however pip3 gives 'commandnotfound' exception, which I'm looking into. Oh, it would be nice to be able to just learn to code!

Comment: Can you provide exactly what you're typing into the command prompt and the exact output? Sounds like a possible typo.

Comment: Gator, added it to bottom of my original post.

Comment: That would suggest that the Script folder for your Python3 is not in your PATH variables. You can add it to your PATH or try using the full path explicitly like `C:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe install pyperclip` (Of course use the path to *your* Python3 directory)

Comment: Here is the thing; my python31 directory never had a scripts folder until I added one(or at least it didn't at that time) a few weeks ago now I think about it. For what reason though, I can't remember. Again, looking into that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue may have been caused by my version of python(3.1.1). I did come across a discussion of bugs in relation to pip and python 3.1.1, but don't have the links I'm afraid.

After upgrading to python 3.5.2 all issues are now resolved and I am able to run scripts from windows and the command line, importing 3rd party modules as necessary, without issue.

P.S I now have access to "pip3" too.